# Containerize a C# ASP.NET application that refers to a C++/CLI library

Tags: asp.net, .net, docker, dockerfile

I am new to containerization. I have a native C++ library which I need to deploy to Azure App Services. Since Azure app services doesn’t support native C++, I thought of wrapping the native C++ project with C++/CLI wrapper project, and calling that wrapper project from a main C# ASP.NET project that I can deploy to Azure. When running locally, it works fine but I am not able to publish it to Azure App Services. Therefore, can someone please help me write a Dockerfile to build a windows docker image, that I can deploy to Azure, because I can deploy docker container to Azure.

What I have so far is:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /source
COPY . .

RUN dotnet restore “NativeCPPWrapper.sln”
RUN dotnet build “NativeCPPWrapper.sln” -c Release -o /app/build
RUN dotnet publish “NativeCPPWrapper.sln” -c Release -o /app/build

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY - -from=build /app ./
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
ENTRYPOINT [“dotnet”, “NativeCPPWrapper.dll”]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .NET SDK image doesn't have the tools needed to build a C++/CLI image. You're going to need to make your own build image installing the Visual Studio Build tools with the .NET and C++ components. There is a guide for [Installing Build Tools into a container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/build-tools-container?view=vs-2022), but it may be easier to start with the [Dockerfile used for the .NET SDK framework image](https://github.com/microsoft/dotnet-framework-docker/blob/main/src/sdk/4.8.1/windowsservercore-ltsc2022/Dockerfile). Note that neither example includes all the components you'll need, but you can find the full list [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-build-tools?view=vs-2022&preserve-view=true). Hard to say not knowing your project's details, but I suspect you'll want the components from the framework SDK Dockerflie linked above and the workload `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.VCTools` and component `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.CLI.Support`

Comment: Thanks for your response. Starting at mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2022 as my base image, I need to install .NET 6.0 SDK, ASP.NET runtime, and C++ redistributable (VC_redist.x64.exe). I create a fresh VM and these three tools are enough to run my project. Do you have ideas on how to create a docker image that has these three tools installed on it? Thank you.

Comment: The links above should be able to get you an image for building your project. For your runtime image: [How to install vc_redist in nanoserver · Issue #40131 · dotnet/runtime](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/40131) suggests that installing VC_redist.x64.exe in a container may not be supported, so your best option would be to copy the redist from the build image or use [static linking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/deployment-in-visual-cpp?view=msvc-170#static-linking) so you don't need the redist on the final container.